# sidebar is hanging over page wrapper tag

Tags: css

In my attempt to be terribly clever and have my #secondary sidebar sit on top of the slideshow on my homepage, I have somehow made the area dangle over the #wrapper on all the secondary pages.  Have added a removed a whole bunch of div tags, nudged things around and tried everything else I can think of.  Anyone have a suggestion how to fix this?
This is the homepage: http://emgraphics.net/joyful/ and the sidebar dangles on any other page (the shame!) Thanks!

Comment: Elaine... please don't ask questions without showing the needed code to reproduce the issue. This is a Community-based website, and both question-code and Answer-code should be available for everyone even in the future ( when your site will be long forgotten :) ) So don't just link-to-web, but paste the smallest sample to reproduce the issue and only than (if you want!) go setup a jsBin.com example if you want to get a good answer - fast.

Comment: never had a problem getting specific help before.

Comment: Elaine, I hope I was clear in my previous comment. Other people might have a similar issue, so let's not be selfish ;) Otherwise I'm afraid your question will be put on hold cause it lacks of sufficient information to diagnose the problem. [Read this before you post your next question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have a problem once you add content to those pages, though. Not sure what the issue is. An absolutely positioned element is taken out of the document flow, so the wrapper will not take any notice of the sidebar. You could alternatively float it and give it a negative top margin on the home page.